# "Attempted import error: 'authReducer' is not exported from './authReducer'. "

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**actually, I'm trying to import a function from JS file called authReducer.js but I'm unable to do so.

In authReducer.js I tried to store that function in const variable in the name of authReducer and then tried to export it but Still same error

**index.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

import {authReducer} from './authReducer' //I'm getting error here

export default combineReducers({
    auth:authReducer
});
```

**authReducer.js**

```
const initialState={
    isAuthenticated:false,
    user:{}
}


export default function(state=initialState,action){
    switch(action.type)
    {
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Both are located in the same folder.

Answer (score 4):

Change your import from:

```
import { authReducer } from './authReducer'
```

to:

```
import authReducer from './authReducer`'
```

Comment: @AvinasshBharadhwaj ;)

Answer (score 2):

Default exports don't need curly braces around them, those are for named exports.

```
/*  somewhere.js  */
const Potato = 5;
const Chernobyl = "hello";

export { Potato };
export default Chernobyl;
```

and then when importing:

```
import Chernobyl, { Potato } from "somewhere";
           ^           ^
       default       named
```

Answer (score 2):

Your import statement should look like this as your function is a default export. You only use {} if it's a named export.

```
import authReducer from './authReducer'
```